# automounting encrypted partition on boot: how to make init parse crypttab before fstab?

Tags: boot, mount, encryption, release-jolnir, home

I’m running elementaryOS 6.1 and so close to getting automounting my encrypted partition on boot and throwing in the towel.

first some context, I have /home in an encrypted partition that as a workaround, I can mount by entering its password on boot if I have this in my /etc/crypttab:

```
home UUID=<UUID of encrypted home partition> none luks
```

I’ve been using my system this way for years and now that I am transitioning this build to a headless server, it won’t work to have to enter a password all the time.

This is the line in /etc/crypttab that is not working as intended:

```
home UUID=<UUID of encrypted home partition> /dev/disk/by-uuid/<UUID of boot partition>:/keyfile luks,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/passdev
```

I set everything up using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/997668/1034628).

I found an [auto_unlocker.sh script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59487/how-to-configure-lvm-luks-to-autodecrypt-partition/656889#656889) that allows me to put this in my /etc/crypttab instead:

```
home UUID=<UUID of encrypted home partition> /dev/disk/by-uuid/<UUID of boot partition of extern micro SD>:/crypt/keyfile luks,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/auto_unlocker.sh
```

I’m clear it works because if I execute:

```
sudo cryptdisks_start home
```

This creates /dev/mapper/home without requesting a password if my micro SD with the key is plugged in (yeay!) and asks for a password if the micro SD is not plugged in.

What I’ve also confirmed is once I manually run the above command and reissue a request to mount all disks:

```
sudo mount -a
```

I exit my console tty and return to the graphical login screen and because /home is mounted, it is now able to log into the desktop.

my current hypothesis is my encrypted home is not mounted to /dev/mapper/home before fstab wants to mount it to /home.

I’ve put asterisks (*) on the relevant lines from dmesg:

```
[    3.812316] systemd[1]: Created slice system-modprobe.slice.
[    3.812621] systemd[1]: Created slice Cryptsetup Units Slice.
[    3.812883] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[    3.813146] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[    3.813203] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    3.813376] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    3.813424] systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
[    3.813435] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
[    3.813443] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[    3.813454] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[    3.813525] systemd[1]: Listening on Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs.
[    3.813614] systemd[1]: Listening on LVM2 poll daemon socket.
[    3.813972] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    3.814047] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[    3.814086] systemd[1]: Listening on initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    3.814235] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[    3.814305] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    3.814389] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    3.814467] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    3.814518] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    3.815320] systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
[    3.816268] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...

[*   3.817595] systemd[1]: Mounting /run/systemd/cryptsetup/keydev-home...

[    3.818955] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
[    3.820163] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Trace File System...
[    3.821854] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[    3.823162] systemd[1]: Starting Availability of block devices...
[    3.824662] systemd[1]: Starting Set the console keyboard layout...
[    3.826019] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel...
[    3.827930] systemd[1]: Starting Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling...
[    3.829155] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module chromeos_pstore...
[    3.829204] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
[    3.830604] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module efi_pstore...
[    3.832400] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module pstore_blk...
[    3.833756] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module pstore_zone...
[    3.835010] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module ramoops...
[    3.835578] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
[    3.837457] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[    3.839098] systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[    3.842890] systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
[    3.844261] systemd[1]: Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
[    3.846456] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[    3.846639] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.

[*   3.846776] systemd[1]: run-systemd-cryptsetup-keydev\x2dhome.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
[*   3.846782] systemd[1]: run-systemd-cryptsetup-keydev\x2dhome.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
[*   3.847546] systemd[1]: Failed to mount /run/systemd/cryptsetup/keydev-home.
[*   3.847696] systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Cryptography Setup for home.
[*   3.847771] systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local Encrypted Volumes.
[*   3.847837] systemd[1]: cryptsetup.target: Job cryptsetup.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
[*   3.847849] systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /dev/mapper/home.
[*   3.847912] systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /home.
[*   3.847995] systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
[*   3.848056] systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Job local-fs.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
[*   3.848078] systemd[1]: home.mount: Job home.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
[*   3.848086] systemd[1]: Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/mapper/home.
[*   3.848158] systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-mapper-home.service: Job systemd-fsck@dev-mapper-home.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
[*   3.848165] systemd[1]: dev-mapper-home.device: Job dev-mapper-home.device/start failed with result 'dependency'.
[*   3.848170] systemd[1]: systemd-cryptsetup@home.service: Job systemd-cryptsetup@home.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.

[    3.848239] systemd[1]: Unnecessary job for /dev/disk/by-uuid/d9bdcdff-ae52-4ddc-83de-6208cb1610db was removed.
[    3.848357] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Debug File System.
[    3.848496] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Trace File System.
[    3.851407] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none.
[    3.853684] systemd[1]: Finished Availability of block devices.
[    3.856035] systemd[1]: Finished Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel.
[    3.856463] systemd[1]: modprobe@pstore_zone.service: Succeeded.
[    3.856960] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module pstore_zone.
[    3.857967] systemd[1]: Finished Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[    3.859400] systemd[1]: Finished Uncomplicated firewall.

[*   3.859607] systemd[1]: Reached target Block Device Preparation for /dev/mapper/home.
```

Anyone have any ideas why my encrypted partition is failing to mount as /home on boot?

Is there any way to check and/or define that /home depends on /dev/mapper/home and ensure they are created in the correct order?